# What does 'Set runtime path of <path> to ""' mean in Yocto log?

Tags: installation, yocto, bitbake

I'm using the [libiio](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/57509/) recipe in my Yocto build, and in the `log.do_install` file for the recipe there are lines like:

```
-- Installing: /home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/usr/bin/iio_info
-- Set runtime path of "/home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/usr/bin/iio_info" to ""
```

The binary referenced is not included in the final image.

What do these lines mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yocto logs, the message "Set runtime path of  to """ indicates that the RPATH (Runtime Path) for a binary or shared library is being set to an empty string. The RPATH is used by the dynamic linker to find shared libraries that a binary depends on during runtime.

Setting the RPATH to an empty string means that the dynamic linker will only search for shared libraries in the system's default library search paths (e.g., /lib, /usr/lib). It will not search for libraries in custom paths specified by the RPATH. This is usually done to ensure that the executable or library uses the shared libraries available on the target system, rather than relying on any specific paths that may not be applicable to the target.